# Filesystem Gives Error : chrono - Expection Unhandled

Tags: c++, directory, filesystems

I want to write code that gets all `.txt`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.doc` and `.docx` files from a given directory and write them to an USB drive.

Here I use `C:\\Users\\{Windows Username}\\Desktop` as the target directory, and `E:\\Targets` as the USB drive. And it is all correct.

When I was writing code, it did not throw any errors until I compiled it.

When it compiles, it only reads 4-5 files and then throws an error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB27A2CB69 in MyTestCodes.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory location 0x000000C8444FE940

Code :

```
#include "MyTestCodes.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string getPath = "C:\\Users\\niko\\Desktop";
    string format,name,path;
    fs::create_directory("E:\\Targets");

    for (const auto& targetPath : fs::directory_iterator(getPath))
    {
        path = targetPath.path().generic_string();
        name = getName(path);
        format = ext(path);
        cout << "path : " << path << endl;
        cout << "name : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Format : " << format << endl;

        if (format == ".txt" )
        {
            cout << "TEXT!";
            string targetText;
            ifstream targetFile(path);
            bool fileAvailable = targetFile.is_open();

            if (fileAvailable)
            {
                getline(targetFile, targetText);
                ofstream textFile("E:\\Targets\\" + name + format);
                bool fileWorked = textFile.is_open();

                if (fileWorked)
                {
                    textFile << targetText;
                    textFile.close();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(format == ".jpg" || format == ".jpeg" || format == ".png" || format == ".doc" || format == ".docx")
        {
            ifstream targetFile(path, ios::binary);
            bool fileAvailable = targetFile.is_open();
            ofstream file("E:\\Targets\\" + name + format, ios::binary);

            if (fileAvailable)
            {
                 file << targetFile.rdbuf();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

MyTestCodes.h :

```
#pragma once

//Libraries Used
#include <iostream> //Input/Output Stream For Console
#include <string>   //For String
#include <fstream>  //File Stream 
#include <vector>   //Changable Index Structure
#include <Windows.h>//For System Commands
#include <algorithm>//Easy Sorting For Arrays/Vectors ...
#include <iomanip>  //For Outputting With Given Precision
#include <cmath>    //Easy Math Functions
#include <stdio.h>  //Standard Input/Output For Given Types
#include <conio.h>  //For getting Key Presses
#include <ctime>    //For getting real time
#include <filesystem>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h>
#include <mciapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
    
using namespace std;    // Standard namespace
namespace fs = filesystem;

//For Getting File's Format On Given Path
string ext(string path) 
{
    ifstream CFile(path); //Checking/Reading File
    bool opened = CFile.is_open(); //bool For Checking
    if (opened) // If Available
    {
        string ext = ""; //Set Extension To Nothing
        size_t size = path.size(); //Get Size Of Path
        size_t lastPos = size;     //Get LastPos(Will Be Used Later)
        char letter;               //Letter For Given Position
        bool ThereIsDot = false;   //Check If There Is Format
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) //Loop To Extract Chars
        {
            letter = path[i];  // Get Char On Given Index
            if (letter == '.') // If Symbol Is Dot 
            {
                lastPos = i;  // Starting Index Of Format
                ThereIsDot = true; // There Is Format
            }
        }
        if (ThereIsDot) //If Format Is Given
        {
            for (size_t i = lastPos; i < size; i++) //Loop For Format Chars
            {
                letter = path[i]; //Get Char On Given Index
                ext += letter; //Get Format 
            }
            return ext; //Give Extension Of File
        }
        else
        {
            return "ERROR"; //Give ERROR If There Is No Extension
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "ERROR"; //Give ERROR If File Not Opened
    }
}



string getName(string target)
{
    size_t size = target.size();
    char symbol;
    size_t lastPos = size;
    string result;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        symbol = target[i];
        if (symbol == '/' || symbol == '\\')
        {
            lastPos = i;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = lastPos + 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        symbol = target[i];
        if (symbol == '.')
        {
            break;
        }
        result += symbol;
    }
    return result;
}
```

My Terminal Looks Like This :

```
path : C:/Users/niko/Desktop/ALPLogo.lnk
name : ALPLogo
Format : .lnk
path : C:/Users/niko/Desktop/Arduino IDE.lnk
name : Arduino IDE
Format : .lnk
path : C:/Users/niko/Desktop/Data
name : Data
Format : ERROR
path : C:/Users/niko/Desktop/desktop.ini
name : desktop
Format : .ini
path : C:/Users/niko/Desktop/Dev-C++.lnk
name : Dev-C++
Format : .lnk
path : C:/Users/niko/Desktop/Discord.lnk
name : Discord
Format : .lnk
```

And My Desktop Folder:
[image: Desktop]

When I Change Path To `C:\\Users\\niko\\Desktop\\{Any File On Desktop}` It Works.
But I Don't Know Why.

How To Fix This Error?

Comment: ***How To Fix This Error?*** Start with using your debugger to try to determine the cause of the problem. Which line of your program did it stop on?

Comment: BTW, the filesystem library already has functions to get the name and extension of a file. Not sure why you are rolling your own code for that: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) There is also functions to copy a file: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy)

Answer (score 0):

`std::filesystem::directory_iterator` iterates over *all* files not just "regular" files (e.g.: folder) which might give you interesting results.
So I would recommend checking it:

```
for (const std::directory_entry& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator (path))
{
  if (is_regular_file(entry)
  {
    // your code
  }
}
```

This might catch some unwanted results.
If you also want to check subfolders use [recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator).
As it been mentioned in the comments also consider [filename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) and [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy). You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: 'if(is_regular_file(entry))' Does Work, But Does Not Check Every File, Also When I Try To Use 'recursive_directory_iterator' It Does Give Me Same Error On Chrono.@Cryptolis

Comment: ,Also When I Try Differenet Paths With recursion It Works : For Example I Tried 'C:' And It Read Almost 1000 Files, But On Desktop It Gaves Error Very Quickly